# Is there a way to set a daily reminder without it cluttering up my Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

In Google Calendar is there a way to set a daily reminder without it cluttering up my Calendar?

e.g. Say I need to take my vitamin pills every morning at 7 am (just a hypothetical example I made up). I need a reminder that I can address with some flexibility (i.e. Not an alarm that keeps ringing) and this also makes sure that if I all I miss it in the morning I can then keep the notification pending and mark it as done in the evening when I do get back home.

I can set it up as a recurring event in Google Calender that repeats daily with a notification but then it unnecessarily clutters up the UI.

i.e. If I print or browse my schedule etc. this shows up as a event every day. That's not what I want.

I just want a daily notification. I tried to make this its separate calendar and then hide it which works to unclutter the Schedule view etc. as intended. But unfortunately, as soon as I hide it the notification does not trigger at all.

Any ideas how this can be done? If at all it can be done.

Comment: Maybe Google Calendar is not the right tool for those kind of reminders. If you are using a smart phone, you could probably set up a daily _alarm_ (in the Clock app), which would be closer to what you want. Other webapps, like [RMTM](https://www.rememberthemilk.com), offer this functionality as well.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal Thanks. But an alarm keeps ringing till turned off right? I just want an on screen notification.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal I do use RMTM for my ToDo Lists. But I cannot figure how to do this job using RMTM. Any tips?

Comment: I haven't used RMTM extensively, but it seems to be possible to set up a daily reminder at a specified time: http://imgur.com/t4NnhZU

Comment: I use an app called Medisafe to remind me to take my medications.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to do this on your phone, but on your computer you can at least hide the event on the calendar (although using this approach other events are still sized by the event) using a userscript.

Essentially the approach is to find all calendar events of the type specified when the page loads and when the DOM changed and hide them. Here's one way:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google calendar event hider
// @namespace    https://zachsaucier.com/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Hide calendar events specified
// @author       Zach Saucier
// @match        https://calendar.google.com/calendar/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var eventList = [
        "Test event"
    ];

    // The actual functionality to remove the events
    function hideEventsInList() {
        var spans = document.querySelectorAll(".cpchip span, .chip-caption span");

        for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
            var span = spans[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < eventList.length; j++) {
                 if(span.innerText.indexOf(eventList[j]) > -1) {
                     var parent = span.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
                     parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    hideEventsInList();

    var observeDOM = (function() {
        var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver,
            eventListenerSupported = window.addEventListener;

        return function(obj, callback) {
            if(MutationObserver) {
                // Define a new observer
                var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
                    if(mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length )
                        callback();
                });
                // Have the observer observe foo for changes in children
                obs.observe(obj, {childList: true, subtree: true});
            }
            else if(eventListenerSupported ) {
                obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
                obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
            }
        };
    })();

    // Observe a specific DOM element:
    observeDOM(document.body.querySelector("#mainbody"), function() { 
        hideEventsInList();
    });
})();
```

I also uploaded this to GreasyFork for easy install [here](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/30597-google-calendar-event-hider).

Comment: Wow. Great solution! Thanks for the effort. I wish it worked on my phone because that's where I want the reminders to be. I'm toying with the native Android alarm set to repeat everyday with no vibrate n no sound. Let me see. But a native google calendar solution would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution could be to set one weekly event on the last week day (or last week work day), and then add several notifications to it: on time; one day before; two days before and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In my galaxy phone, I went to my calendar, then the menu, then 'manage calendars' and at the bottom it says 'App Events' I noticed Reminders was listed so I turned it off.
Now my reminders aren't cluttering up my calendar and I still get notified of them each day.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a new Google calendar just for these reminders. It will, of course, show up with all your other calendars on the left. Give it its own name and color.
2. Put at least one reminder in this calendar to test.
3. Check the little color swatch just to the left of the calendar's name. This will hide any events under that calendar. However, if you add an alarm or alarms, you will still see those just as you do for other events with alarms.
4. Check or uncheck the calendars' color swatch to edit or hide.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow that doesn't seem to work for me. If I hide the calendar the notification never triggers. Can you verify this works? I'm trying it on my Android cell's Google calendar app if that matters.

Comment: This will not work. It disables notifications for that entire calendar (purposefully)

Comment: I am using Google's calendar on the desktop, Safari browser, and the alarm shows up while hidden. (Also works with Firefox and Chrome.) I also get the notification on my iPhone. However, I use Pocket Informant on my phone, not Google's native calendar. Note 1) the calendar is hidden on my macBook's Google Calendar, but shows up on Pocket Informant, so this may not be a satisfactory solution if you are mainly concerned about how it looks on a phone. 2) I tried entering a hidden notice both from my phone and from my MacBook and they both worked. I'm sorry that it didn't work for you.

Comment: I suggest modifying this procedure as follows: create a dummy family member google account.  Create the recurring event in the new account.  Invite yourself to that recurring event.  You can toggle the dummy account on or off in the bottom portion of your screen.  I have not tested this, though!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have a Samsung watch? (If you haven't already found a solution?) When I created a daily reminder on my phone (note 10), the reminder showed up as a block on every day. For some reason though, when I created one in the reminder app on my Samsung watch, it only shows as a block for the next day on my calendar. I'm assuming this block will then move to the next day once I click completed as it is set to remind every day.I can live with that but having it blocked off every day just made a mess.